# How do I suppress Swiftmailer errors?

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am using [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) for sending mails in my application. While everything works good, I want to be able to suppress all exceptions thrown by Swiftmailer and simply return false (for instance, running the application on localhost with my GMail SMTP settings throws a timeout fatal exception).

I have the error_reporting set to 0, and I also tried adding a try-catch block, but I have come to understand that the catch block wont really catch the exception.

How can I completely suppress all errors and just return false if something went wrong?

Comment: don't suppress error's, fix them!

Comment: What do you mean exactly, `I have come to understand that the catch block wont really catch the exception`? What have you tried exactly and how did it not work?

Comment: @Dagon I don't want my entire app dying with a fatal error on the screen. I'd rather log the error in the background. And these are errors like SMTP server timeout that happen now and end about which, I cant do much from the application end.

Comment: @jeroen I read somewhere that PHP catch block doesn't work like the C# ones for instance and it will still show the error anyway. I also tried added a global error handler but somehow, this exception just keeps bubbling up (I get a timeout error every now and then, no matter which exception i try to catch).

Comment: Have you tried catching `Swift_TransportException`?

Comment: Yes, and also Exception, Swift_SwiftException and Swift_IoException. No luck :(

Comment: Are you using a framework that perhaps catches the exception before you do?

Comment: @jeroen No, here's the code if you want to take a look at it: [https://github.com/sayakb/sticky-notes](https://github.com/sayakb/sticky-notes) - the email logic is in classes/class_email.php. Right now, it does not have any error handling logic as it hasn't been working for me.